# Missing legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot to show the average number of bikes rent on weekday by hourly using ggplot as shown below in R. Since I have weekday as number in my data, its giving text legend as numbers.

```
ggplot(bike_share_train, aes(x=hour, y=count, color=day))+
    geom_point(data = day_summary_by_hour, aes(group = day))+
    geom_line(data = day_summary_by_hour, aes(group = day))+
    ggtitle("Bikes Rent By Weekday")+scale_colour_hue('Weekday')
```

[image]

I want to change those numbers to weekday names and I tried using below command, but legend is missing in ggplot. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

```
 ggplot(bike_share_train, aes(x=hour, y=count, color=day))+geom_point(data = day_summary_by_hour, aes(group = day)) +
    geom_line(data = day_summary_by_hour, aes(group = day))+
    ggtitle("Bikes Rent By Weekday")+
    scale_colour_hue('Weekday', breaks = levels(bike_share_train$day), labels=c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'))
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me. `library(ggplot2);
dsamp <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ];

ggplot(dsamp, aes(carat, price)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = clarity)) +
  scale_colour_hue("clarity", breaks = levels(dsamp$clarity), labels = paste("lab_", levels(dsamp$clarity)))`

Answer (score 2):

Although the OP found the solution, I'm proposing an alternative approach when each group consist of only one observation.

```
library(ggplot2)
# create some sample data
bike_share_data<-data.frame(hour = c(1.5,2.3,1.3,2.2,1.5),
                        count = c(21,26,30,15,20),
                        day = c("1","2","3","4","5"))
head(bike_share_data)
ggplot(bike_share_data, aes(x=hour, y=count, color=day))+
  geom_point(data = bike_share_data, aes(group = 1))+
  geom_line(data = bike_share_data, aes(group = 1))+
  ggtitle("Bikes Rent By Weekday")+
  scale_colour_hue('Weekday',
                   breaks = levels(bike_share_data$day), 
                   labels=c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
  )
```

[image: Bike Rent by weekday]

Answer (score 1):

My sincere apologies to everyone for my mistake. I extracted the weekday, hour from datetime value but forgot to change the datatype from char to factor for these fields. So, issue in ggplot. I have changed the datatype and checked the ggplot. Now legends are showing.